# Memorize the last radio button clicked

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

Assume a group of 4 radio buttons. The user clicks on the first one, then he for example realizes that he made a mistake and he clicked on the 4th one. Is there a way to memorize just the last one clicked and to make the app forgets that the 1st one was clicked too?

Comment: yes, you can store value in sharedPreference, so you can get what user clicked even after he reopens app

Comment: Yeah you can use sqlite database or sharedPreference...

Comment: @vijay I'm using sqlite actually, and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: when user click button we have to insert sqlite for every clicking.then when ever you want to see the list then select your column and see which button use clicked.My doubt you need last user clicked or what ever user clicked that all list?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example using SharedPreferences. Easier, less cumbersome than Sqlite.

Layout

***demo.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rank_radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/first_radio"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/first_radio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="First" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/second_radio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Second" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/third_radio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Third" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/fourth_radio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fourth" />
    </RadioGroup>


</LinearLayout>
```

Activity

***DemoAppActivity.java***

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class DemoAppActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private RadioButton mFirstRadioButton = null;
    private RadioButton mSecondRadioButton = null;
    private RadioButton mThirdRadioButton = null;
    private RadioButton mFourthRadioButton = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo_app);

        initializeRadioGroup();
    }

    private void initializeRadioGroup() {

        mFirstRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.first_radio);
        mSecondRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.second_radio);
        mThirdRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.third_radio);
        mFourthRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.fourth_radio);

        // Fetching last checked position in preferences
        int lastCheckedPosition = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("last_checked", 0);

        Log.d("TAG", "Fetching last saved position " + lastCheckedPosition);

        switch (lastCheckedPosition) {
        case 1:
            mFirstRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            break;
        case 2:
            mSecondRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            break;
        case 3:
            mThirdRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            break;
        case 4:
            mFourthRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            break;
        default:
            mFirstRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            break;
        }

        mFirstRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        mSecondRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        mThirdRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        mFourthRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        int newCheckedPos = 0;

        if (isChecked) {
            switch (buttonView.getId()) {
            case R.id.first_radio:
                newCheckedPos = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.second_radio:
                newCheckedPos = 2;
                break;
            case R.id.third_radio:
                newCheckedPos = 3;
                break;
            case R.id.fourth_radio:
                newCheckedPos = 4;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (newCheckedPos > 0) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Saving new checked position " + newCheckedPos);

            // Saving checked position in preferences
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
                    .putInt("last_checked", newCheckedPos).commit();
        }

    }

}
```